# "Reach eye care to rural areas"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read in a newspaper the following heading for an article:

> Reach eye care to rural areas: Governor

Is it correct usage of the word *reach*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The verb *[reach](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reach)* is being used here as a synonym for *extend*, but not in a way that you would see it in standard writing.

A better way to phrase the headline without rearranging it would be

> Extend eye care to rural areas: Governor

Comment: Also fine: "Make eye care reach rural areas: Governor", "Reach rural areas with eye care: Governor", or "Eye care should reach rural areas: Governor".

Comment: ‘Reach’ is an alternative to ‘extend’ in some contexts, but none of the M-W examples is on the pattern ‘reach something to something’ and I have been able to find any citations supporting such use in the OED.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Thanks, I changed my answer to note standard usage.

Comment: X can reach to Y, and X can reach Y, but X cannot reach Y to Z.